# Careers CV - Possible Export Functionality

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, cv, export

Has anybody thought about/seen the ability to export your careers.stackoverflow.com CV to a PDF (or Word, or OpenDocument, etc.)?

Seems like it would be a really nice feature to offer so that we have a common format for our CVs.

Comment: Or Word, since so many HR departments and recruiters require it.  (BTW: If you take an HTML resume and give it a .doc extension, Word will open it and they'll be none the wiser.)

Comment: That's a fantastic trick, Paul.

Comment: Though, people who require my resume in word are not usually people I want to work for...

Comment: @Paul T: that'll work great for HR people that physically read the resume, but less well for those that feed it to an automated import system.

Comment: @Joel Good thing that is their problem at that point, so long as the resume doesnt disapear

Comment: You can always just open it yourself, then re-save it as a doc(x)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has now been implemented.  To access this functionality, please click "My Profile":[image: my profile tab]

and then click "create pdf":

[image: create a pdf]

Comment: hope to see a "create word" link soon.

Comment: To be precise, the "create pdf" button (at time of writing) is in the "Profile Settings" view.  The flow is: My Profile, Profile Settings, create pdf.

Comment: Year 2016, see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266897/222087)

Comment: And what about export CV to JSON? Is it available or planned?

Answer (score 32):

I used to maintain my CV in RTF, DOC and HTML....

After years of exporting and uploading my CV in multiple formats I gave up and now just maintain it in **the only format recruiters, employers and clients ever ask for - Word Format**.

**I'd like to make careers.stackoverflow.com the only place I need to edit to update my CV** - and have it instantly updated on the web, available in the stack overflow search and downloadable as a word document.

Answer (score 6):

Love the request; just had someone today ask me if they could get a PDF version from me. I didn't have one, obviously.

Oh, as someone who's used ActivePDF: Use something else, if at all possible.

Answer (score 6):

2016-10:

Now it moves to develop story tag of your home page
[image]

Comment: It looks like we can't anymore change the sections to go into the PDF. :/

Answer (score 4):

You can convert SO resume to PDF/DOC/HTML using this site: http://lab.madgex.com/hresume/

Comment: Not sure who is getting it wrong careers.stackoverflow.com or madgex, but it completely ignores any styling within the experience sections.

Comment: Link gives: `404 - File or directory not found.`

Comment: Site is gone as of the time of this comment.

Answer (score 4):

Careers public CVs are marked-up using the [hResume microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hresume).  This support has improved considerably recently.

As Ivo points out, [Madgex's hResume converter](http://lab.madgex.com/hresume/) will give you a PDF or Word version.  I can't imagine you'd want to distribute a CV with such plain formatting, but it could serve as a starting point.

Careers also has a print style sheet defined, so you can generate a quick B&W* copy of your CV by just printing to PDF (or XPS, whatever floats your boat).

<sub>*This stylesheet also removes things like navigation links, the SO Careers logo, and underlining on links.  Under IE it also tries to place page breaks in intelligent places.</sub>

Comment: I would like a PDF that is in color with the links still intact, so when I send it to them they can click on it and get to my live site.  No reason to have a boring resume.

Answer (score 3):

Yes please.  And I'd like to see the export have an option to include a live link in the PDF/RTF to the online version, so that when my HR department forwards me an emailed CV to review, I can get to the live version (and the associated user's questions and answers) with a single click.

Answer (score 3):

It would also be nice to be able to export as a (*gasp*) plain-text version. A lot of these companies make me paste my resume into a little text box (even when they want to interview/hire me - just so it's "in their system") and I always have to manually format the darn thing!

I can see the export feature now: "Please enter how many columns wide the textbox is along with its maximum character limit."

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to offer something like HR-XML - there are already XSLT transforms available on SourceForge to convert to HTML / PDF; I'm sure anyone worth employing could do DOCX as well if required.

Also *some* recruitment companies actually accept HR-XML "as is".

Answer (score 0):

I would be happy with a HTML that embeds all the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, I just view my public CS... then **File -> Print -> Save As PDF**.

I love that it has a style sheet defined. And I hate that some sites require a PDF or Word doc.

Answer (score 0):

I usually open the URL from **Libreoffice (OpenOffice) Writer**. Then it gets imported. After that you can make edits.

So the steps are:

Get Libreoffice writer (it's open source) and open the Careers URL in it.
When it asks for a file name, **paste the https url and press enter**.

Libreoffice will import the page. At this moment I see it imports 2 formats. One is rich text, the other is plain. Both formats are imported one after the other. You have to remove the first one. The plain format is more suitable for Word.

Now you can edit, save, print, convert. Do whatever you wish.