# Is it possible to export Stack Overflow CVs to LinkedIn?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

How can I import my Stack Overflow CV to LinkedIn?

I saw [this Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27614/careers-cv-possible-export-functionality) but it seems to be mainly about exporting to PDF format.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Overflow CVs [support the hResume format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28375/should-careers-stackoverflow-com-support-hresume) so if LinkedIn can import that, then yes.

Comment: so, I guess the answer is NO