# Where did the export CV option go?

Tags: support, jobs

It [used to exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27614/148169), but I can't seem to find it for the life of me on the new Stack Overflow Jobs site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's buried, but still there.

Click on the `Edit CV` tab, then the `Settings` button the right. This shows you two options to export as either PDF or Markdown.

[image: Export]

Comment: Ah, **Settings**, because *of course* export is a setting :P (sarcasm directed at SO, of course. In all sincerity, thank you)